# JSON Array of Objects Formatting for Postman Test

Tags: arrays, json, object, postman

I'm trying to take the results of one request in Postman and put them into a second. The first request's format is as follows (leaving out some extraneous objects):

```
[
   {
      "lfidField": "11111",
      "featureField": "Logging",
      "keyField": "VP316coUxxxxxxx"
   },
   {
      "lfidField": "11111",
      "featureField": "Premium",
      "keyField": "egg0+4Bkmkzsxxxxxxx"
   }
]
```

There are more objects (as many as 8 in total, but the number can change), but the featureField will always have a unique value. I need to get a simple output of:

```
{
   "Logging": "VP316coUxxxxxxx",
   "Premium": "egg0+4Bkmkzsxxxxxxx"
}
```

And obviously that would need to iterate to any number of objects from the first request. I'm extremely new to this, so I'm hoping someone can help.

Comment: you want python code or something?

Comment: Need this in Chai.js formatted for a Test in Postman, sorry I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tab Test of Request 1:

```
const res = pm.response.json();
let log = "";
let pre = "";
res.filter((item) => {
    if (item.featureField === 'Logging'){
       log = item.keyField;
    }

    if (item.featureField === 'Premium'){
       pre = item.keyField;
    }
});
pm.environment.set("Logging", log);
pm.environment.set("Premium", pre);
```

In tab body of Request 2:

```
{
   "Logging": "{{Logging}}",
   "Premium": "{{Premium}}"
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the response: "There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined". I've tried moving a few things around and don't see an obvious problem.

Also, can I use "collectionVariables" instead of "environment" to keep my variables contained to the collection rather than the environment? I get the same error either way, just curious.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. The code should be in Test tab, not Pre-request tab. I’ve updated the answer

Comment: That did it! Thank you so very much!!!

NOTE: changing "environment" to "collectionVariables" worked just fine.

Comment: Yeah, no big differences between `environment` and `collectionVariables`. You can choose one of them, and it will work.